# How to display word dictionary with custom keypad in android

Tags: android

I have successfully created a custom key pad in my application but i am unable to find out how to display a dictionary of words like android default keypad which appear at the top whenever we type.

Comment: Did you develop an Soft Keyboard(like the default android one), or just simply added buttons to your activity for A, B, etc?

Answer (score 0):

1st you need to take an `AutoComplete TextView`
Afterwards , you need to follow this example:
[Creating a Search Interface](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html)
In this example the ListView's `Data-Source` is being changed when the text is entered in `Search Bar`.
You need to change the `Data-Source` of `AutoComplete TextView` as the user enters different texts.
I hope this will solve your problem.